# Update or insert different condition

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this data :

```
user_id            id_game           level                score
10                 1                  1                   200
10                 1                  1                   400
10                 1                  2                   500
10                 2                  1                   230
11                 1                  1                   345
```

This data I want to migrate to a new table, the idea is if level,id_game and user_id are already inserted, I look to the max score. So for this example I want to save :

```
user_id           id_game             level               score
10                 1                   1                  400
10                 1                   2                  500
10                 2                   1                  230
11                 1                   1                  345
```

I want to do in a single sql, I tried somethink like this :

```
INSERT INTO %s (user_id, id_game, level, score)
                      VALUES (%d, %d, %d, %d) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_id = %d, id_game = %d, score = %d.
```

But not work. Can you help me please ?

Comment: *But not work*  means? any error?

Comment: A query using the aggregate MAX() function and GROUP BY might help; but what is the key based on?

Comment: @MarkBaker If the score is bigger for a specified user, id_game, level we update the score, if doesn't exist specified user,id_game,level we insert

Comment: @Jens If the score is bigger for a specified user, id_game, level we update the score, if doesn't exist specified user,id_game,level we insert

Comment: That's why you aggregate `MAX(score)` and `GROUP BY user_id, id_game, level`

Comment: and use `ON DUPLICATE` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user_id 
     , id_game
     , level
     , MAX(score) score
  FROM this_data
 GROUP
    BY user_id
     , id_game
     , level;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a simple query.

```
CREATE TABLE <TARGET_TABLE_NAME> SELECT USER_ID,ID_GAME,LEVEL,MAX(SCORE) FROM <SOURCE_TABLE_NAME> GROUP by 1,2,3;
```